# ffmpeg convert variable framerate movie to pics

Tags: ffmpeg, movie

is it possible to use ffmpeg to convert a movie with **variable framerate** to a sequence of still pics without duplicates?
I tried something like:

```
ffmpeg -i vid.avi pic%d.png
```

but each frame generates thousands of pictures. I also tried:

```
ffmpeg -i vid.avi -r 10 pic%d.png
```

but I still have lots of duplicates AND some frames are missing

is it possible to specify something like "-r natural"???

TIA

Comment: wow still no answer? is it so amazing???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit late, but...

```
ffmpeg -vsync 2 -i <input movie> <output with %d>
```

will do the trick. For example:

```
ffmpeg -vsync 2 -i "C:\Test.mp4" "C:\Thumbnails\Test%d.jpg"
```

will create exactly one jpeg per frame in the C:\Thumbnails folder, and each jpeg will be sequentially numbered with no gaps or duplicates in numbering.

Comment: And it _is_ pretty amazing no one else answered.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it as soon as I remember why I needed that :D